# SQL - How to Query Parent Child Records by Descending TimeStamp

Tags: sql, parent, parent-child

Here is my table

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| CommentId  | ParentId  |  Timestamp    | CommentText  |
+------------+---------+-----------+--------------------+
|          1 |      NULL |  Jan 1 2:00pm |          a   |
|          2 |      NULL |  Jan 1 2:01pm |          b   |
|          3 |         1 |  Jan 1 3:03pm |          c   |
|          4 |         2 |  Jan 1 5:00pm |          d   |
|          5 |         2 |  Jan 1 5:01pm |          e   |
|          6 |      NULL |  Jan 1 8:00pm |          f   |
|          7 |         1 |  Jan 1 7:00pm |          g   |
|          8 |         6 |  Jan 1 9:04pm |          h   |
|          9 |         1 |  Jan 1 8:05pm |          i   |
|         10 |      NULL |  Jan 1 9:04pm |          k   |
+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
```

Currently I am using the following SQL to return the comments ordered by parent

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Comments c
ORDER BY COALESCE(c.ParentId, c.Id)
```

The result is this:

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| CommentId  | ParentId  |  Timestamp    | CommentText  |
+------------+---------+-----------+--------------------+
|          1 |      NULL |  Jan 1 2:00pm |          a   |
|          3 |         1 |  Jan 1 3:03pm |          c   |
|          7 |         1 |  Jan 1 7:00pm |          g   |
|          9 |         1 |  Jan 1 8:05pm |          i   |    
|          2 |      NULL |  Jan 1 2:01pm |          b   |    
|          4 |         2 |  Jan 1 5:00pm |          d   |
|          5 |         2 |  Jan 1 5:01pm |          e   |
|          6 |      NULL |  Jan 1 8:00pm |          f   |    
|          8 |         6 |  Jan 1 9:04pm |          h   |    
|         10 |      NULL |  Jan 1 9:04pm |          k   |
+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
```

I need to get the results in a Descending timestamp order. The result set should look like:

```
 +------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| CommentId  | ParentId  |  Timestamp    | CommentText  |
+------------+---------+-----------+--------------------+         
|         10 |      NULL |  Jan 1 9:04pm |          k   |
|          6 |      NULL |  Jan 1 8:00pm |          f   |    
|          8 |         6 |  Jan 1 9:04pm |          h   |    
|          2 |      NULL |  Jan 1 2:01pm |          b   |    
|          5 |         2 |  Jan 1 5:01pm |          e   |
|          4 |         2 |  Jan 1 5:00pm |          d   |
|          1 |      NULL |  Jan 1 2:00pm |          a   |
|          9 |         1 |  Jan 1 8:05pm |          i   |
|          7 |         1 |  Jan 1 7:00pm |          g   |
|          3 |         1 |  Jan 1 3:03pm |          c   |    
+------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
```

The following does not work:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Comments c
ORDER BY COALESCE(c.ParentId, c.Id), Timestamp DESC
```

Comment: why you say that it doesn't work? i think you are only missing a DESC in your order by

Comment: Yes, if I add the DESC without the Timestamp it will most of what I want. The only thing it doesn't do is order the replies (parentId != NULL) in a descending order. I realized that I didn't order the replies in descending order in my question. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this query returns rows in the order that you want:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Comments c
ORDER BY
  COALESCE(ParentID, ID) DESC,
  ParentID is not null,
  Timestamp DESC
```

It orders rows in descending order by ParentID if it is not null, otherwise by ID, then rows with null go at the top, and then by timestamp desc.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.

Comment: what DBMS are you using? you could try to sobstitute the row `ParentID is not null,` with this: `CASE WHEN ParentID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,`